# Can you get a bounty while you're in the passive mode?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I tried the passive mod for the first time because some monkeys killed me all the time.
Now they l aren't able to hit me and shoot me, but they're able run over me with the car and i died again....!

So now I ask you: Can I also get a bounty (by a player or by a NPC) while i'm in the passive mode? If yes, must they run over me to get the bounty or are they able to shoot me again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible to get a bounty while in passive mode.**

Running you over is a way to kill you while in passive mode.
Another way to get killed by other players while in passive mode is getting hit by helicopter blades. The helicopter blades will also kill through walls, even when being in your own apartment if you get to close to the windows.

**I recommend going into a store or your apartment and stay away from the windows** if you are in passive mode and have a bounty on your head.

Comment: So can set a player a bounty on me or only NPC's?

Comment: Both.  NPCs and players can set a bounty on you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot be in passive mode if you have a bounty on you. It will not allow you, so yes you can get a bounty on you while you are in passive mode, but you won't be in passive mode once the bounty is put on.